# Bounty game, multiple pots, who gets the chip?

Tags: rules

The following situation happens in a bounty game:

Hero is short-stacked, goes all in.

Villain #1  has a bigger stack, raises all in.
Villain #2 and #3 have even bigger stacks, and call.

Chips are separated into main pot and side pot.

At the showdown, Hero has best hand and takes the main pot.
Villain #2 and #3 tie, and split the side pot.
Villain #1 is knocked out.

Who gets the bounty?

Hero has the best hand, but not enough chips to  knock out #1.  #2 and #3 have worse hand, but it was  their bets that eliminated #1.

If it goes to #2 or #3, which gets it? The one with the bigger stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chopped bounty normally. You of course correctly mentioned that Villain #2 & #3 are the only ones who can knock out Villain #1.

So you are, of course, not eligible for it. Bounty should be chopped between Villain #2 & #3, their overall stack size is not important for this hand as neither are all-in and lost, and they both cover the all-in players.

If this bounty wasn't chopped and I was one of the Villain's who split the side pot I'd be kicking up a fuss.

Answer (score -2):

it is basically whom ever had the most chips starting the hand, and who covered the all in.